# How add bootstrap to YesodForm

Tags: haskell, yesod, yesod-forms

I need Help to add BootStrap to My YesodForm Project. Can you help me, guys ?

Thats my code. I just want add BootStrap styles to add to my html components
I already read aloot tutorials but are complexive, i am new at Haskell. I Need a simples thing just to that simple project. Thank.s

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, TypeFamilies, QuasiQuotes,
             TemplateHaskell, GADTs, FlexibleInstances,
             MultiParamTypeClasses, DeriveDataTypeable,
             GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving, ViewPatterns, EmptyDataDecls #-}
import Yesod
import Database.Persist.Postgresql
import Data.Text
import Text.Lucius
import Control.Monad.Logger (runStdoutLoggingT)

data Pagina = Pagina{connPool :: ConnectionPool}

share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
Animals json
   nome Text
   idade Int
   deriving Show

Users json
   nome Text
   login Text
   senha Text
   deriving Show
|]

mkYesod "Pagina" [parseRoutes|
/ HomeR GET
/animal/cadastro AnimalR GET POST
/animal/checar/#AnimalsId ChecarAnimalR GET
/erro ErroR GET

/login LoginR GET POST
/usuario UsuarioR GET POST
/perfil/#UsersId PerfilR GET
/admin AdminR GET
/logout LogoutR GET
|]

instance Yesod Pagina where
    authRoute _ = Just LoginR

    isAuthorized LoginR _ = return Authorized
    isAuthorized ErroR _ = return Authorized
    isAuthorized HomeR _ = return Authorized
    isAuthorized UsuarioR _ = return Authorized
    isAuthorized AdminR _ = isAdmin
    isAuthorized _ _ = isUser

isUser = do
    mu <- lookupSession "_ID"
    return $ case mu of
        Nothing -> AuthenticationRequired
        Just _ -> Authorized

isAdmin = do
    mu <- lookupSession "_ID"
    return $ case mu of
        Nothing -> AuthenticationRequired
        Just "admin" -> Authorized 
        Just _ -> Unauthorized "Acesso Restrito para Administrador"

instance YesodPersist Pagina where
   type YesodPersistBackend Pagina = SqlBackend
   runDB f = do
       master <- getYesod
       let pool = connPool master
       runSqlPool f pool

type Form a = Html -> MForm Handler (FormResult a, Widget)

instance RenderMessage Pagina FormMessage where
    renderMessage _ _ = defaultFormMessage
------------------------

formAnimal :: Form Animals
formAnimal = renderDivs $ Animals <$>
           areq textField "Nome: " Nothing <*>
           areq intField "Idade: " Nothing

formUser :: Form Users
formUser = renderDivs $ Users <$>
           areq textField "Nome: " Nothing <*>
           areq textField "Login: " Nothing <*>
           areq passwordField "Password: " Nothing

formLogin :: Form (Text,Text)
formLogin = renderDivs $ (,) <$>
           areq textField "Login: " Nothing <*>
           areq passwordField "Senha: " Nothing           

getAnimalR :: Handler Html
getAnimalR = do
           (widget, enctype) <- generateFormPost formAnimal
           defaultLayout $ do 
           toWidget [cassius|
               label
                   color:blue;
           |]
           [whamlet|
                 <form .form-horizontal method=post enctype=#{enctype} action=@{AnimalR}>
                     ^{widget}
                     <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar Animal">
           |]

getPerfilR :: UsersId -> Handler Html
getPerfilR uid = do
      user <- runDB $ get404 uid
      defaultLayout $ do
          toWidget $ $(luciusFile "templates/perfil.lucius")
          $(whamletFile "templates/perfil.hamlet")

getUsuarioR :: Handler Html
getUsuarioR = do
           (widget, enctype) <- generateFormPost formUser
           defaultLayout [whamlet|
                 <form method=post enctype=#{enctype} action=@{UsuarioR}>
                     ^{widget}
                     <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
           |]

postAnimalR :: Handler Html
postAnimalR = do
           ((result, _), _) <- runFormPost formAnimal
           case result of 
               FormSuccess anim -> (runDB $ insert anim) >>= \piid -> redirect (ChecarAnimalR piid)
               _ -> redirect ErroR

postUsuarioR :: Handler Html
postUsuarioR = do
           ((result, _), _) <- runFormPost formUser
           case result of 
               FormSuccess user -> (runDB $ insert user) >>= \piid -> redirect (PerfilR piid)
               _ -> redirect ErroR

getHomeR :: Handler Html
getHomeR = defaultLayout [whamlet|Hello World!|]

addStyle :: Widget
addStyle = addStylesheetRemote "http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.0/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css"

getAdminR :: Handler Html
getAdminR = defaultLayout [whamlet|
    <b><h1><font size="11"> Bem vindo ao Painel Administrativo</font></h1></b>
|]

getLoginR :: Handler Html
getLoginR = do
           (widget, enctype) <- generateFormPost formLogin
           defaultLayout [whamlet|
                 <form method=post enctype=#{enctype} action=@{LoginR}>
                     ^{widget}
                     <input type="submit" value="Login">
           |]

postLoginR :: Handler Html
postLoginR = do
           ((result, _), _) <- runFormPost formLogin
           case result of 
               FormSuccess ("admin","eitapleuga") -> setSession "_ID" "admin" >> redirect AdminR
               FormSuccess (login,senha) -> do 
                   user <- runDB $ selectFirst [UsersLogin ==. login, UsersSenha ==. senha] []
                   case user of
                       Nothing -> redirect LoginR
                       Just (Entity pid u) -> setSession "_ID" (pack $ show $ fromSqlKey pid) >> redirect (PerfilR pid)

getChecarAnimalR :: AnimalsId -> Handler Html
getChecarAnimalR pid = do
    animal <- runDB $ get404 pid
    defaultLayout  [whamlet|
    <font size="10">Perfil do Pet</font><br>
        <p><b> Nome do Pet:</b>  #{animalsNome animal}  
        <p><b> Idade do Pet:</b> #{show $ animalsIdade animal} Anos
    |]

getErroR :: Handler Html
getErroR = defaultLayout [whamlet|
    <h1>Falha no Cadastro !</h1>
|]

getLogoutR :: Handler Html
getLogoutR = do
     deleteSession "_ID"
     defaultLayout [whamlet| 
         <h1> <b>Logout</b> efetuado com sucesso! </h1>
     |]

connStr = "dbname=d4673as0stmsm7 host=ec2-54-221-225-242.compute-1.amazonaws.com user=nzjfptmglfomng password=fyYms4A9T8gkP4_Go8GswcfIiE port=5432"
```

main::IO()
main = runStdoutLoggingT $ withPostgresqlPool connStr 10 $ \pool -> liftIO $ do 
       runSqlPersistMPool (runMigration migrateAll) pool
       warp 8080 (Pagina pool)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it in your `Handler` function like this:

```
getUsuarioR :: Handler Html
getUsuarioR = do
       (widget, enctype) <- generateFormPost formUser
        defaultLayout $ do
           addStylesheetRemote "http://remote-bootstrap-path.css"
           [whamlet|
                 <form method=post enctype=#{enctype} action=@{UsuarioR}>
                     ^{widget}
                     <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
           |]
```

Also if you are new to Haskell, I would suggest you to learn some minimal Haskell before diving into Yesod.

Comment: Hi, Sibi. Thanks for the answer, but when i try add this that you posted and try do build i get this error:   The last statement in a 'do' block must be an expression
      (widget, enctype) <- generateFormPost formUser defaultLayout
                           $ do { addStylesheetRemote "http://remote-bootstrap-path.css";
                                  [whamlet|
                 <form method=post enctype=#{enctype} action=@{UsuarioR}>
                     ^{widget}
                     <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
           |] }

Comment: Thanks Sib. It Worked, dont know why, no error. Now, to use the BootStrap i just need set the .class of bootstrap in my elemments, Right ?

Answer (score 0):

Especially for a first project I would advise to use the scaffolded site. You can get it by following the quick start guide on the Yesod home page. Not only do you get sensible default settings, but it also has the bootstrap css already integrated.

The downside is of course that the scaffolding throws a lot of stuff and opinions at you that you might not want or not agree with. But even if you don't like the scaffolding, you can always keep one in a separate folder and just take inspiration from it and incorporate parts of it into your own site - like the integration of bootstrap or jquery.

What you need to do next is to add the appropriate classes to your html elements. There are two ways to do that, depending on the context. In your own widgets you just add them like you would any other class (with a point in front of it). If you use code that is generated, for example for forms or for yesod-table, you often have a choice between different rendering functions. For example you can render forms in two columns by using the *renderTable* rendering function. But there is almost always another function with a name like *renderBootstrap* which will render the content as plain divs with bootstrap classes.

So all in all Yesod is extremely well integrated with bootstrap. Even too much in my personal opinion. But in your case it should make your task comparatively easy after the initial setup confusion.